# Compiled html does not invoke the ng-click

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angularjs-directive

I am loading a partial view with input fields and a submit button.

The partial view is loaded from my ASP.NET MVC controller, but somehow the button is not invoked by my `ng-click`.

---

#### Example

**index.controller.js**

```
$scope.addClient = function() {
$http.get('/FileMaintenance/AddClient')
    .then(function (response) {

            var divTemplate = response.data;
            divTemplate = $sce.trustAsHtml(divTemplate);
            $scope.chosen_view = divTemplate;
            var element = angular.element(document.getElementById('btnAddCompany'));
            element.append(divTemplate);
            $compile(element)($scope);
    },
        function(error) {
            alert('An error occured in retrieving view. ' + error.message);
        });

};
```

**index.html**

```
<div id="file_maintenance_view_area">
    <div ng-bind-html="chosen_view">

    </div>
</div>
```

**Loading the partial view from ASP.NET mvc**

```
<div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="addClient()">Add Client</a>
</div>
```